# Enable checkbox if other checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table with multiple columns, 2 of them being checkboxes. However, I only want the first column of checkboxes to be enabled on page load. I only want the second column of checkboxes to be enabled if a checkbox is checked in the first column.

My current code will do that but I am wanting the checked checkbox to only enable/disable the specific checkbox in that same row, not all of them in the entire column.

How can I do this? This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.paid').attr('disabled', true);

  $('.selected').change(function() {
    $('.paid').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--checkbox that is enabled on page load-->
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="check" class="selected" name="selected"></td>

<!--checkbox that will be enabled/disabled based on checkbox above-->
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="paid" class="paid" name="selected"></td>
```

Comment: give that checkbox a unique id and apply js accordingly

Comment: Your question is fairly easy to answer if we can see all the html of the table, or at least the full table row. Could you upload that?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I disagree.  Being tabluar data, this lends itself to the use of `closest('tr')` followed by a find of a checkbox that is not itself.  An id or class is not necessary in this use case.

Comment: I didn't say they were in different rows.  He says they are in the same row, which is why the closest() approach works.

Comment: @Taplar my bad thanks for correcting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.paid').attr('disabled', true);

  $('.selected').change(function() {
    //find only the paid in the same row as the selected checkbox
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.paid').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="check" class="selected" name="selected"></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="paid" class="paid" name="selected"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="check" class="selected" name="selected"></td>
                <!-- checkbox that will be enabled/disabled based on checkbox above --> 
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="paid" class="paid" name="selected"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.paid').attr('disabled', true);

  $('.selected').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.paid').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
});
```

That will make sure it find the `.paid` checkbox next to your `.selected` checkbox.